# SQL Query returning "None" instead of row

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm working on a light login, and have a tabled titled Users. I'm trying to take my login form POST body and verify it across the database.

**Values from form:**

```
user = request.form['username']
password = request.form['password']
```

**SQL Statement:**

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE '(%s)'" % user)
row = cur.fetchone()
```

**Users Table:**

[image]

So on a `POST` request from my form, here is what is printed:

```
Print(user, password) =  ph104694 Password123
Print(row)  = None
```

So you can see the row is being returned as `None` when the data absolutely exists. If I change `user` to something I know is incorrect, I'm getting the same results, but if I change the table from `Users` to something like `Users2` I'm met with a `no table exists` error which is fine. So despite matching data existing something about my statement isn't allowing it to produce that row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're search expression is evaluating to `(ph104694)` which clearly *doesn't* exist in the data you showed.
2. There is no reason to use the LIKE operator here and it probably runs counter to what you want to do (match the single record exactly matching the user ID that was entered).
3. This is the classic example of code that is subject to an SQL injection attack.  You should never, never, ever use string interpolation to build an SQL string like this.  Instead, use parameter substitution.

Taken all together, you want something like this:

```
 cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = ?", [user])
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, so I've found out. Either way none of my SQL will ever be used anyways, so just needed to get over the hump. ;) I'll accept this answer if the gentleman who helped me solve the issue below doesn't update their answer to reflect the issue/solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your query string evaluates to `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE '(ph104694)'"`.

Note the parentheses which aren't in the actual username.

Also, you almost certainly don't want to use `LIKE`.

What you want is `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = 'ph104694'"`

Which would create with `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '{user}'".format(user=user)`

Also, you can (and should) parameterize this as

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = :user", {user: user})
```